# How to view files using an editor which have a certain matching content

Tags: grep

How to view files using an editor (say vi) which have a certain matching content
For example, I want to search for something like "Purchase Order" in a recursive fashion and load files which has that content

Comment: Do you want 1 `vi` session, i.e. `vi a.txt b.txt c.txt` or multiple sessions, i.e. `vi a.txt; vi b.txt; vi c.txt` ?

Comment: one session is what I need

Comment: `vi $(grep -l 'pattern' *.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate over the results of *grep* expression and open each of them using *vim*, you do the below command:

```
for file in `grep -l "Purchase Order" *`; do vi $file ; done
```

Comment: I would prefer to open all the files in a single go and grep should be recursive. the above command has to be done for all folders